# Execute SQL scripts on VM Machine using release azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using IIS Deployment template in Release pipeline to deploy MVC application to VM and it is working fine. But after deploying application, we want to run any ad-hoc sql changes using script files in SQL server using custom task [Run SQLCMD Scripts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DrJohnExtensions.RunSqlCmdScripts) from VSTS market place.

[image: Relese pipeline]
Relese pipeline, scripts are in zip file, Can anyone suggest what we should key-in in "Path to folder containing SQLCMD script files"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try referencing the variable
`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

Answer (score 0):

In Release Pipeline, the artifacts will be downloaded to the path : `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)`.

According to your screenshot, I noticed that you are using the "Extract files" task. This task will find the zip files in the $(System.ArtifactsDirectory) and extract it.

The unzipped folder name is set in the "Extract files" task (Destination folder).

[image: Extract files task]

So you could try to use the following path:

```
$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/Destination folder name
```

You can also expand this path according to the actual location of the file.

Hope this helps.